# Can anyone give examples of when rvalue references in C++ prove very beneficial?

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue

This feature seems to be interesting and useful, but I would like to know its use case in practical applications. Like the difference it created, before adding this feature and once it got introduced.

Comment: Introduced in c++11. Allow to *move* resource, and implement a correct `unique_ptr` :-).

Comment: [Googling sounds like a good solution sometimes](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/rvalue-references-and-move-semantics-in-c++11.html).

Comment: You probably want [what are move semantics?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106110/2069064)